# Configuração de formato de data no VueJS/Quasar Framework

Tags: javascript, data, vue.js, formatação

Tenho um campo para inserção da data de nascimento, e quero que o resultado da inserção seja formatado em 'DD-MM-AAAA'. Consegui fazer com que a data seja exibida no input na formatação desejada, porém quando envio a data para o banco de dados ela vai assim: "1997-08-19T00:00:00.000-03:00".

Criei uma função para formatar a data, mas não deu muito certo:

```
formatarData () {
    let data = this.pessoa.nascimento
    this.pessoa.nascimento = date.formatDate(data, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  }
```

Agora está indo para o banco assim: "NaN- NaN-0NaN", como formatar para que saia da forma desejada??

Comment: Esse _"campo para inserção"_ é de texto ou é um calendário com datas para clicar? O que é `date` nessa segunda linha?

Comment: É um Datetime, um calendário para clicar e escolher as datas, mas já consegui resolver usando o Moment.JS.
E o date é uma importação do Vue

Comment: Já conseguiste resolver a pergunta ou a parte do input da data? (e o que é `date` que tens aqui `date.formatDate(`?)

Comment: Consegui resolver a pergunta como um todo. O `date` é um recurso do Vue, que pode ser usado através de um `import`, porém não consegui fazer o que eu queria usando ele, então utilizei o Moment.JS, que funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Ok, então podes apagar a pergunta ou dar uma resposta. Se responderes tens de clarificar mais a pergunta, pois ainda não dá para perceber estando de fora.

Comment: Ok, vou responder ela, para que possa ajudar alguém que venha a precisar futuramente, fique à vontade para editar se achar necessário... Agradeço a sua atenção

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para quem precisar de ajuda, consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
formatarData () {
    let data = this.pessoa.nascimento
    this.pessoa.nascimento = moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
  }
```

Utilizei o [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) para fazer a conversão do formato da data.
`this.pessoa.nascimento` se refere ao objeto que estou convertendo a data de nascimento.

Espero que esse esclarecimento seja útil para mais pessoas assim como foi para mim.

Answer (score -5):

Você pode fazer assim no seu Modelo:

protected $casts = [
'status' => ServerStatus::class,
];